# Amazon Linux AMI release 2010.11.1 corresponds to which RHEL version (4/5/6)?

Tags: linux-distributions, rpm, yum, amazon-ec2, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am using the default Amazon Linux AMI in an EC2 instance - Amazon Linux AMI release 2010.11.1. I can see that it's a Redhat based system, but after trying many tools (/etc/issues, uname -a, lsb_release), I cannot tell which version of RHEL or CentOS is it based on. I need to get some packages that are not available in Amazon's package repos. I have list of custom yum repos that I can use, but since I don't know which RHEL version is the Amazon AMI based on, I cannot choose from different versions of repos.

How can I find whether it's running RHEL 4/5/6 (or their CentOS counterparts)?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the answer is not straight-forward. Here's a [response](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=51647&tstart=0#194519) from Amazon rep on AWS forum:

> The Amazon Linux AMI is based on RHEL
>   5.x and parts of RHEL6. One of our goals is binary compatibility with
>   RHEL 5.x, and therefore CentOS5.x.
>   Astute users will note that our kernel
>   is based on 2.6.34, and we have
>   engineered the image to conform to a
>   cloud environment. For example, the
>   lack of Xorg support helps to keep the
>   images small and lean. The goal of the
>   Amazon Linux AMI is to provide an
>   image for use in the cloud and to
>   serve as reference image of EC2 best
>   practices. The maintenance (security,
>   enhancements, features and bug fixes)
>   for the image will come directly from
>   Amazon, while maintaining maximum
>   compatibility, security and
>   functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell what RedHat based release you are running by looking at the content of /etc/redhat-release.

It is possible that this file may have been removed but it that is the case some tools will not accept they are running on a RedHat'ish system.

EDIT: Try running one (or more) of the following commands

```
rpm -qa | grep el
rpm -qa | grep centos
rpm -qa | grep rhel
```

These will show if any RHEL 5/6 or CentOS 5 packages are installed.

If you see some **el5** and some **centos** you are running CentOS5. If you see only **el5** you are running RHEL 5 (CentOS 5 and RHEL 5 packages are interchangable anyway).

If you see el4 it's RHEL 4 or possibly CentOS 4 - I'd think this unlikely.

If you see **rhel6** or **el6** it's RHEL 6.

You could also try

```
rpm -qa | grep release
```

Which may also give the game away.

Comment: Yes, /etc/redhat-release is not there. After I installed lsb, there is /etc/redhat-lsb directory though.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon's user guide ([at the bottom of the page](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/)) mentions that it's mostly compatible with CentOS5 or later.

You should be able to compare your kernel version to the CentOS releases to pick the closest match. Based on the kernel version listed in their [release notes](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/latest-release-notes/), they may be tracking Fedora a bit more closely than Enterprise. RHEL6 is still at 2.6.32.